# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL from an android client

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am building several Android apps that leverage Google Cloud services. I successfully created an app using Cloud Endpoints and built-in Datastore. But, I was unable to access this data from another app using Remote API. Hence, I'm considering switching to Cloud SQL as it allows multiple apps to connect to it.

My understanding is that you cannot connect non-GAE apps to Cloud SQL. Do I need to expose a GAE web service that my android clients can call?

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does Remote API have to do with this? That's a tool for development. You already have Cloud Endpoints, that's what you use to access data.

Answer (score 3):

Just about any app can talk to Cloud SQL -- see https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external -- but you probably don't want to connect directly from a mobile app since you would have to open your database to any external host, and a spike in load could lock up your database.

A better solution would be to use Cloud Endpoints or similar to expose an API, which would talk to Cloud SQL on the backend.

Comment: I can't find a guide anywhere showing how to use Cloud Endpoints to create an API with Cloud SQL as the backend...